# In php for insert query how to use json to show the inserted data?

Tags: php, json

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users(firstName,lastName,userEmail,userPhone,userPass) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$email','$phone','$password')";
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: I want to show the inserted query in the form of json. Please can anyone suggest me with an answer.

Comment: 1. stop using `deprecated+removed mysql_*` library, move towards `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. 2. you don't want to run query,just want to make query in json format,why? or run the query and get the result in json format?

Comment: First off welcome to SO. As @AlivetoDie said stop using `mysql_*` which is old and not in use any more. Switch to newer `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and also look in to using prepared statements because the way you're using your variables will lead to a SQL injection attack. Now to your problem to tell you the truth it's really not clear what you want to do. If you can make the question more clear we can help you to solve it. What do you want to do really? you want to show a success message or the data that got inserted ?

Comment: I want to run the query and get the result in json format

Comment: I want to get the data that's inserted in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wish to display

```
echo JSON_encode(
    "firstName" : $fname,
    "lastName" : $lname,
    "userEmail" : $email,
    "userPhone" : $phone,
    "userPass" : $password
);
```

If you want to get the data from database then after insertion retrieve that data using either id or email and then display it in above way

Answer (score 0):

After your insertion to get the last insert id from db and fetch the row using that insertion id and the result value pass into the json_encode(); function.

Use the following function: json_encode(Retrial array value);

Comment: When trying to use this function I am getting entire code in the browser. I used it as follows echo json_enocde($query);

Comment: Before you execute the query you fill find the last insert row id and it user into where condtion to get the particular element id.